# Cannot delete duplicate certificate

Tags: keychain, certificate

I have a duplicate certificate in my keychain which I cannot seem to be able to delete. If I delete it from the keychain app by first unlocking the system keychain and then right clicking and selecting 'delete', nothing happens and the certificate still stays there.

I tried to do it from the terminal by first finding the certificate with:

```
$ security find-certificate -a -c "Apple Distribution: Klikkie B.V. (T6R6F8DT6A)"
```

But the output is not clear to me:

> keychain: "/Users/ramy/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
> version: 512
> class: 0x80001000
> attributes:
> "alis"="Apple Distribution: Klikkie B.V. (T6R6F8DT6A)"
> "cenc"=0x00000003
> "ctyp"=0x00000001
> "hpky"=0x6C8C43A8219FB00B61FABF26700A676F33C4CD4D  "l\214C\250!\237\260\013a\372\277&p\012go3\304\315M"
> "issu"=0x30753144304206035504030C3B4170706C6520576F726C647769646520446576656C6F7065722052656C6174696F6E732043657274696669636174696F6E20417574686F72697479310B3009060355040B0C02473331133011060355040A0C0A4170706C6520496E632E310B3009060355040613025553  "0u1D0B\006\003U\004\003\014;Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority1\0130\011\006\003U\004\013\014\002G31\0230\021\006\003U\004\012\014\012Apple Inc.1\0130\011\006\003U\004\006\023\002US"
> "labl"="Apple Distribution: Klikkie B.V. (T6R6F8DT6A)"
> "skid"=0x6C8C43A8219FB00B61FABF26700A676F33C4CD4D  "l\214C\250!\237\260\013a\372\277&p\012go3\304\315M"
> "snbr"=0x30A166E4E270E98C1CA5BC577C807D39  "0\241f\344\342p\351\214\034\245\274W|\200}9"
> "subj"=0x30818D311A3018060A0992268993F22C6401010C0A543652364638445436413136303406035504030C2D4170706C6520446973747269627574696F6E3A204B6C696B6B696520422E562E2028543652364638445436412931133011060355040B0C0A5436523646384454364131153013060355040A0C0C4B6C696B6B696520422E562E310B3009060355040613025553  "0\201\2151\0320\030\006\012\011\222&\211\223\362,d\001\001\014\012T6R6F8DT6A1604\006\003U\004\003\014-Apple Distribution: Klikkie B.V. (T6R6F8DT6A)1\0230\021\006\003U\004\013\014\012T6R6F8DT6A1\0250\023\006\003U\004\012\014\014Klikkie B.V.1\0130\011\006\003U\004\006\023\002US"

I showed the output only of one certificate. First of all it's not clear how to distinguish one from another, second it's not clear where to find the hash. The intent is to use the delete-certificate command but I don't how to identify the one that I need to delete. And if I try deleting by name I am not sure what happens, but I don't want to delete the wrong one.

I even tried following [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7357200), or giving the least restrictive permissions to my Keychain with chmod but I am still unable to delete the certificate. At the moment this is preventing me from building apps with Xcode and I am surprised that Apple makes it so much of a problem. Can anybody suggest me a solution?

[image]

Comment: The certificates have different expiration dates so the newer one is likely a renewed key, that uses the same key pairs. Perhaps something changed in your Developer account that caused a renewal of the certificate.

Comment: Indeed the certificate was renewed. Let's say that I want to keep the new one and delete the old one. I don't understand how to get rid of it.

Comment: Could you try deleting the certificate *without* doing a search? That is, delete "klikkie" from the search field, scroll down until you find the certificate, right-click it and select "Delete".